# I am trying to create a subscription but an error occurs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:603:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\github\V2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\github\V2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at C:\github\V2\app\API\register.js:84:13
    at C:\github\V2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:371:9
    at C:\github\V2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:260:32
    at C:\github\V2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:510:55
    at C:\github\V2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:371:9
    at C:\github\V2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sessions.js:136:24 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

This is the code in my file that is causing the problem.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb+srv://web:U*****qe8xe@web-nodejs.b5fppl0.mongodb.net/";
const cookisSession = require('cookie-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongodbsession = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { response } = require('../database');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // เรียกใช้งาน body-parser

app.use(session({
   secret: 'Session-service',
   resave: false, // ต้องการบันทึกค่าหรือไม่
   saveUninitialized: false, // ต้องการบันทึกค่าหรือไม่
   maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // กำหนดระยะเวลาการเปิดตัวคุณภาพการเชื่อมต่อกับคอมพิวเตอร์
   store: new mongodbsession({
       uri: 'mongodb+srv://web:U******qe8xe@web-nodejs.b5fppl0.mongodb.net/',
       dbName: 'webjs',
       collection: 'sessions'
   })

}));





app.post('/a-login', (req, res) => {
 const username = req.body.username;
 const password = req.body.password;


 // เข้ารหัส password
 const hash = require('crypto').createHash('sha256');
 hash.update(password);
 const password_hash = hash.digest('hex');

 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err;
   var dbo = db.db("webjs");
   dbo.collection("users").find({ name: username, password: password_hash }).toArray(function(err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     if (result. Length > 0) {
       res.send("ยินดีต้อนรับคุณ " + username);

       

     } else {
       res.send("ชื่อผู้ใช้หรือรหัสผ่านไม่ถูกต้อง");
     }
     db.close();
   } );
 } );
 if (result.length > 0) {
   // บันทึกค่าลง session
   req.session.username = username;
   req.session.gemd = result[0].gemd;
   req.session.email = result[0].email;
   req.session.id = result[0]._id;
   req.session.save();


 } else {
   res.send("ไม่สมารถเข้าสู่ระบบได้");
 }
} );
module. Exports = app;
```

How should I fix this problem?

This text was translated by google.

Comment: You should tag the correct language instead of C++

Comment: You are using a very insecure password hash algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the session (as it'd send a header) after you've `res.send()`ed some content.

Additionally, since the Mongo connection stuff is async, you can't have an `if` after that block and expect it to work correctly.

Something like the following might be closer to what you want, but I would recommend refactoring things to use `async`/`await`. Also, **absolutely don't use sha256 for password hashing.**

```
app.post("/a-login", (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    // เข้ารหัส password
    const hash = require("crypto").createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(password);
    const password_hash = hash.digest("hex");
    db.db("webjs")
      .collection("users")
      .find({ name: username, password: password_hash })
      .toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result.length > 0) {
          // บันทึกค่าลง session
          req.session.username = username;
          req.session.gemd = result[0].gemd;
          req.session.email = result[0].email;
          req.session.id = result[0]._id;
          req.session.save();
          res.send("ยินดีต้อนรับคุณ " + username);
        } else {
          res.send("ชื่อผู้ใช้หรือรหัสผ่านไม่ถูกต้อง");
        }
        db.close();
      });
  });
});
```